# How to increase the PDA size after deployment with anchor framework

Tags: anchor, solana-program, solana-cli, anchor-lang, anchor-spl

Is there a way to increase PDA size after contract deployment using anchor framework. Here is the reference of doing the same with realloc, https://dev.to/jacobcreech/how-to-change-account-size-on-solana-55b4, is something available with anchor framework as well?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Is there a way to resize an account's data field?](https://solana.stackexchange.com/questions/540/is-there-a-way-to-resize-an-accounts-data-field)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You could use the `realloc` constraint on anchor too.

This is a duplicate of [this question](https://solana.stackexchange.com/a/541/1708)

the code snippet from the question

```
#[derive(Accounts)]
pub struct Example {
    #[account(mut)]
    pub payer: Signer<'info>,
    #[account(
        mut,
        seeds = [b"example"],
        bump,
        realloc = 8 + std::mem::size_of::() + 100,
        realloc::payer = payer,
        realloc::zero = false,
    )]
    pub acc: Account<'info, MyType>,
    pub system_program: Program<'info, System>,
}
```

Comment: seems like only once the account size is updated, i tried checking the space with the command `let info = await provider.connection.getAccountInfo(<pdaAccount>).space;` and this function is returning same size at each call